# No sound after connecting to Bluetooth device wf-1000xm3

Tags: bluetooth, pipewire

Bluetoothctl shows my WF-1000xm3 ear phones connected. But, the earphones do not give the accoustic feedback 'bluetooth connected' and also sound does not work.

Below is the output of bluetoothctl.

```
$ bluetoothctl connect 14:3F:A6:81:00:38

Attempting to connect to 14:3F:A6:81:00:38
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:81:00:38 RSSI: -56
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:81:00:38 Connected: yes
Connection successful
```

I use EndeavourOS and installed PipeWire. The troubleshooting section of the Arch's PipeWire Wiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire), covers the problem "No sound after connecting to Bluetooth device". It refers to a udev script (https://gist.github.com/tinywrkb/04e7fd644afa9b92d33a3a99ab07ee9e), from which I copied this terminal comand

```
(pactl list sinks|grep Name|grep 'bluez.*.a2dp.sink'|sed 's/Name: //'|sed 's/\s//')
```

Which did not show any available devices.

Any idea, what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still having this issue almost a year later, but I recently experienced this on a Lubuntu install. If you are still having this problem see if you have bluez-alsa-utils installed. If you do uninstall it. It worked for me.

Comment: I still have this issue and am using EndeavourOS.. unfortunately bluez-alsa-utils is not installed on my OS, so that did not help me.